# How to animate UICollectionViewCell on selection using IGListKit

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, iglistkit

I have been unable to use the didHighlightItem and didUnhighlightItem functions to correctly animate when a cell is clicked, as I am unable to access the cell's section number. I was wondering whether I am solving the problem incorrectly, or whether there is a way of accessing the SectionController's section index in the collection view. My code is as follows:

```
class PersonSectionController: ListSectionController {
    var current: Person?

    override init() {}

    override func didUpdate(to object: Any) {
        if let person = object as? Person {
            current = person
        }
    }

    // Number of items displayed per object
    override func numberOfItems() -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    // Dequeue and configure cell
    override func cellForItem(at index: Int) -> UICollectionViewCell {}

    // Returns the required cell size at the given index
    override func sizeForItem(at index: Int) -> CGSize {}

    override func didHighlightItem(at index: Int) {
        if let viewController = self.viewController as? PeopleViewController {
            if let cell = viewController.peopleCollectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)) {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
                    cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.95, y: 0.95)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func didUnhighlightItem(at index: Int) {
        if let viewController = self.viewController as? PeopleViewController {
            if let cell = viewController.peopleCollectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: index)) {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
                    cell.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to access the cell from the `collectionContext`:

```swift
override func didHighlightItem(at index: Int) {
    guard let cell = collectionContext?.cellForItem(at: index) else { return }        
    // Animation stuff
}
```